# Linkedlist and arraylist speed comparison in c++

Tags: c++, arraylist, linked-list

I have to make two types of list data types for my data structures class, an ArrayList and a Linkedlist. The ArrayList will be based on arrays and the LinkedList will be based on nodes, then i need to compare their performance on adding (on the desired position), updating and removing elements from front, end and middle of the list for lists with 100,1000 and 10000 elements. The point of the homework is to show that linked lists are faster. I made both structures and all the functions but when i test them the result always shows that my array lists are faster. Can someone please tell me why my linked lists works slower?

```cpp
struct ArrayList {
    int* head;
    int size;
    void build();
    void add(int, int);
    void update(int, int);
    void remove(int);
    void print();
    void clear();
};

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

struct LinkedList {
    Node* head;
    int size;
    void build();
    void add(int, int);
    void update(int, int);
    void remove(int);
    void print();
    void clear();
};

    void LinkedList::build() {
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

void LinkedList::add(int index, int value) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    n->data = value;
    if (head == NULL) { // adding to an empty list
        head = n;
        size++;
    }
    else {
        if (index == 0) {  // adding at front                     
            n->next = head;
            head = n;
            size++;
        }
        else if (index < size) { // adding inside
            Node* p = head;
            int c = 1;
            while (c < index) {
                p = p->next;
                c++;
            }
            n->next = p->next;
            p->next = n;
            size++;
        }
        else if (index == size) { // adding at the end
            Node* p = head;
            while (p->next) {
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = n;
            size++;
        }
        else {
            cout << "index out of range";
        }
    }
}

    void ArrayList::build() {
    size = 0;
    head = new int[size];
}

void ArrayList::add(int index, int value) {
    int* arr = new int[size + 1];
    if (index == size) {        //adding at the end
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = head[i];
        }
        arr[size] = value;
        delete head;
        head = arr;
        size++;
    }
    else if (index < size) {      //adding inside or front
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            arr[i] = head[i];
        }
        arr[index] = value;
        for (int i = index; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i + 1] = head[i];
        }
        delete head;
        head = arr;
        size++;
    }
    else {
        cout << "index out of range.";
    }
}

Testing code

     ArrayList* a = new ArrayList();
    LinkedList* l = new LinkedList();
    l->build();
    a->build();
    int n = 10000;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l->add(i, i);
        a->add(i, i);
    }
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    a->add(n, 1);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin);

    auto begin2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    l->add(n, 1);
    auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end2 - begin2);

    cout << "with " << n << " " << "elements" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "ArrayList adding time: " << elapsed.count() << " nano-seconds" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "LinkedList adding time: " << elapsed2.count() << " nano-seconds" << endl;
```

Comment: You'll find that in practice linked lists are horribly slow outside of a few use cases because their data is extremely slow to iterate. With an array, all the data is in one straight line in one block of memory. The CPU can easily predict where you're going next and has probably already cached it. With a linked list, you need to find a link before you can find the next link, making it hard to predict and preload the next node. You can insert and remove linked list nodes easily, but finding the node to remove or the insertion point is a brutal slog.

Comment: However, if you've already found the node or the insertion point, insert or remove is lightning fast, but that's not what your code is doing. `void LinkedList::add(int index, int value)` always starts at the beginning of the list and works through each and every node until it finds the insertion point (O(N) made worse by low [spatial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)).

Comment: [Here is an excellent piece on linked list vs array](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists) With a linked list, the data is not compact and the access order isn't very predictable.

Comment: Side note: A good ArrayList implementation would potentially waste storage to speed itself up. Rather than add 1 to the size every time, allocate more than you need (doubling the size is simple and popular) so that you don't have to reallocate and copy everything every time. With a modern CPU the wasted space will be virtual until the memory is used and assigned actual storage

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243671/discussion-on-question-by-fatih-arslan-linkedlist-and-arraylist-speed-comparison).